# send HttpPostedFileBase in less time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am uploading file and sending it to controller, it takes 2 minutes to reach at server. Is it any way to send a file of 380KB in less time on form submit

From

```
<input type="file" />
```

To

```
public void uploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
```

[image: This is my internet speed]

Comment: it,s shouldn't so much time.. There must me something else.. coz 380kb is  not so much heavy

Comment: I believe either network OR server speed is very slow. otherwise it will not take time to upload 380KB file.

Comment: How can i assure that either its network or what issue??

Comment: I have added my internet speed in question too. Please check

Comment: Is it a single 380KB file? Otherwise using archives might reduce some overhead

Comment: yes a single 380kb file... but size vary too... its a end-user application ..Maximum size limit is 1MB